# proplem gorm many to many get list

Tags: go, go-gorm

proplem:
error is invalid field found for struct honardari/api/models.CategoryModel's field
PlayList: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner
interface

pleas help me

```
packages models :

type PlayListModel struct 
{
    Id             int             `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    Published      string          `gorm:"column:published" json:"published"`
    Type_PlayLIST1 string          `gorm:"column:type_playlist1" json:"type_playlist1"`
    Type_PlayLIST2 string          `gorm:"column:type_playlist2" json:"type_playlist2"`
    Type_PlayLIST3 string          `gorm:"column:type_playlist3" json:"type_playlist3"`
    Type_PlayLIST4 string          `gorm:"column:type_playlist4" json:"type_playlist4"`
    Price          int             `gorm:"column:price"  json:"price"`
    Price_Orginal  int             `gorm:"column:price_orginal" json:"price_orginal"`
    Main_img       string          `gorm:"column:main_img" json:"main_img"`
    UserId         int             `gorm:"column:user_id"`
    LIkesCount     string          `gorm:"column:likes_count" json:"likes_count"`
    ViewsCount     string          `gorm:"column:views_count" json:"views_count"`
    Content        string          `gorm:"column:content"  json:"content"`
    Title          string          `gorm:"column:title" json:"title"`
    Categories     []CategoryModel `gorm:"many2many:app_products_playlist_category"`
}

type CategoryModel struct {
    ID       string          `grom:column:"id" json:"id"`
    Name     string          `grom:column:"name" json:"name"`
    Img      string          `grom:column:"img" json:"img"`
    Slug     string          `grom:column:"slug" json:"slug"`
    Row      string          `grom:column:"row" json:"row"`
    ParenID  string          `grom:column:"parent_id" json:"parent_id"`
    PlayList []PlayListModel `gorm:many2many:app_products_playlist_category`
}
type PlayListCategoryModel struct {
    PlayListID int `gorm:"primary_key;column:playlist_id" json:"playlist_id"`
    CategoryID int `gorm:"primary_key;column:category_id" json:"category_id"`
    PlayListModel
    CategoryModel
}

func (PlayListCategoryModel) TableName() string {
    return "app_products_playlist_category"
}

func (category *CategoryModel) TableName() string {
    return "app_category_category"
}

func (playlist *PlayListModel) TableName() string {
    return "app_products_playlist"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just a typo, in this code:

```
PlayList []PlayListModel `gorm:many2many:app_products_playlist_category`
```

You need double quotes, so change to this:

```
PlayList []PlayListModel `gorm:"many2many:app_products_playlist_category"`
```

Just advice, use convention instead of configuring everything by yourself, so better should be something like that:

```
type PlayListModel struct
{
    gorm.Model
    ...


type CategoryModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
```

Look, I'm using `gorm.model` and automatically I have ID and others fields.

Comment: add gorm.Model, the answer will come back, but the category is empty

Comment: which answer? can you give more details?

Comment: Categories    in get response  data  return  null complet issue link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579831/gorm-many-to-many-proplem

Comment: Ok, let's see it in another post, I think you can mark this answer as accepted